# Combining vectors in Gensim Word2Vec vocabulary

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

Gensim Word2Vec Model has a great method which allows you to find the top n most similar words in the models vocabulary given a list of positive words and negative words.

```
wv.most_similar(positive=['word1', 'word2', 'word3'], 
                negative=['word4','word5'], topn=10)
```

What I am looking to do is create word vector that represents an averaged or summed vector of the input positive and negative words. I am hoping to use this new vector to compare to other vectors.
Something like this:

```
newVector = 'word1' + 'word2' + 'word3' - 'word4' - 'word5'
```

I know that vectors can be summed, but I am not sure if that is the best option. I am hoping to find out exactly how the above function (most_similar) combines the positive vectors and negative vectors, and if Gensim has a function to do so. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Gensim does not expose a separate function to add/subtract the (unit-normed) vectors in the same way that `most_similar()` does.

Perhaps it should, as that could be generally useful, including in sharing code between other existing methods.

But as an open-source project, you can look at its exact Python code for that operation, and use it as a model for your own calculations.

For the current code defining that function, see:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/ee3d6fd1e33fe39fc7aa31ebd56bd63b1a2a2ed6/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L687

Comment: Great, thank you, seems they are using a mean.

Answer (score 0):

From advice above, I chose to look at Gensim source code and copy their method for averaging the vectors. Here is the code incase it helps anyone else.
Note : this code is copied from gensim, and is just reformatted to return the averaged vector.

```
from gensim import matutils
import numpy as np
from numpy import ndarray, array, float32 as REAL

KEY_TYPES = (str, int, np.integer)

'''
FUNCTION : meanVector(...)
INPUT :
        keyedVectors : word vectors or keyed vectors from gensim model, (model.wv)
        positive : list of words or vectors to be applied positively [default = list()]
        negative : list of words or vectors to be applied negatively [default = list()]
OUTPUT : 
        averaged word vector, [type = numpy.ndarray]
DESCRIPTION :
        allows for simple averaging of positive and negative words and vectors given a gensim model's word vector library.
'''

def meanVector(keyedVectors, positive=list(), negative=list()):
        
    positive = [
            (item, 1.0) if isinstance(item, KEY_TYPES + (ndarray,))
            else item for item in positive
            ]
    negative = [
            (item, -1.0) if isinstance(item, KEY_TYPES + (ndarray,))
            else item for item in negative
            ]
        
    # compute the weighted average of all keys
    all_keys, mean = set(), []
    for key, weight in positive + negative:
        if isinstance(key, ndarray):
            mean.append(weight * key)
        else:
            mean.append(weight * keyedVectors.get_vector(key, norm=True))
            if keyedVectors.has_index_for(key):
                all_keys.add(keyedVectors.get_index(key))
        if not mean:
            raise ValueError("cannot compute similarity with no input")
        
    mean = matutils.unitvec(array(mean).mean(axis=0)).astype(REAL)

    return mean
```

Note: this has not been thoroughly tested.